# Upgrade project from laravel 7 to laravel 10

Tags: laravel

i have a project since 3 years on Laravel 7 on GitHub, i clone the project to my localhost, now i want to upgrade the project to Laravel 10. I get tired to do `composer update` and `npm run dev` and `npm run dev` and `php artisan key:generate` , i get a fatel error.
my composer.json:

```
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "imliam/laravel-env-set-command": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.5",
        "milon/barcode": "^7.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.36",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~4.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
```

i download xampp from near, my php version is 8.1
help me please

Comment: You're supposed to copy the `.env.example` file to `.env` and adjust the settings there. Probably need to run `php artisan key:generate` and maybe some migrations, depends on the project

Comment: fatal error in ```php artisan key:generate```

Comment: That doesn't help. Please [edit] your question and post/append relevant information there, not in the comments. If you need to post error messages post the _complete_ message including file/line numbers etc.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: "_i get a fatel error_" is _not_ the complete error message. Since you want to upgrade, follow Laravel's [upgrade guides] for every version. Good luck

Comment: Missed the upgrade guides link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade - upgrade to 8, then 9, then 10. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why you can't find the .env file is because it's added to the .gitignore file. After installing the composer packages, try running:

composer require maatwebsite/excel:^3.0.1
Please make sure to use the compatable version of the Excel package based on your Laravel version.